# How to validate form data and return back to same page in jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to validate a set of selectboxes in my jsp and if there is any error; it should return an alert-box else the control should get transferred to the servlet. I have tried following -

JSP code -

```
<script language="text/javascript">

function validatesb(){

    var select = document.getElementById('month').value;
    var select1 = document.getElementById('year').value;

    alert(select);
    if(select=="" || select1==""){
        console.log(select);
        return false;
    }       
    return true;
}
```

```
    <form method="post" action="searchresult.do">

    <select id="month" class="required">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled">Month</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select> 

    <select id="year" class="required">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled">Year</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>

    </select> 

    <input type="submit" value="search" onClick='return validatesb();'>

</form>
```

The control is jumping directly to the servlet page. Please help.

Comment: Now, I dont understand why is the console showing [ function validatesb is not defined. ]

Comment: May be missing `</script>` or some problem in `JS`.

Comment: The problem was .. using:

<script> and not <script language="text/javascript">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSP:**

```
<form method="post" action="searchresult.do" onsubmit='return validatesb();'>
...............
<input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
function validatesb(){
    var select = document.getElementById('month').value;
    var select1 = document.getElementById('year').value;

    if(select=="" || select1==""){
        console.log(select);
        return false;
    }
  //NO NEED OF RETURN TRUE       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<form method="post" action="searchresult.do" onsubmit="return validatesb();">
```